# How was Neville Longbottom qualified to be the Chosen One?

Tags: harry-potter

I have read the whole series and watched every movie, but I never caught how Neville could have been the chosen one. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Do you mean, "why did people think the prophecy might have been about either Neville or Harry", or do you mean "how could Neville possibly have defeated Voldemort"?

Comment: Are you sure you actually read all the books?

Comment: yes. yes i am. and i can admit that it is offensive to ask someone that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick reminder of the prophecy made by Prof. Trelawney in front of Dumbledore when applying for the Divination post :

> "The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches... born
>   to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies...
>   and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power
>   the Dark Lord knows not... and either must die at the hand of the
>   other for neither can live while the other survives... the one with
>   the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month
>   dies...."

Man, now that's quite a memorable job interview. Anyway, there are two points to remember :

- The Chosen One kid is born at the end of July ("born as the seventh month dies"). [According to Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/neville-longbottom), Neville was born on July 30th, just one day before Harry.
- His parents went against Voldemort three times ("born to those who have thrice defied him"). Taken from [this interview retranscription](https://web.archive.org/web/20090616145209/http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.html) :

> **SU:** What did the Longbottoms do that they earned that wrath from
>   Bellatrix? Such-- There's three times, like the Potters thrice defied
>   the Dark Lord.
>
> **JKR:** They were efficient! They were efficient. That's all they needed
>   to do to earn her wrath. They were-- They had rounded up Death Eaters,
>   they were very good Aurors, they knew what they were doing, they were
>   responsible for a lot of captures and arrests and imprisonments. And--
>   So there you are.
>
> **MA:** What about the three times-- The thrice-defying of Voldemort?
>
> **JKR:** Of James and Lily?
>
> **MA:** Of Neville's parents. Well, James and Lily, too.
>
> **JKR:** It depends how you take defying, doesn't it. I mean, if you're
>   counting, which I do, anytime you arrested one of his henchmen,
>   anytime you escaped him, anytime you thwarted him, that's what he's
>   looking for. And both couples qualified because they were both
>   fighting. Also, James and Lily turned him down, that was established
>   in "Philosopher's Stone". He wanted them, and they wouldn't come over,
>   so that's one strike against them before they were even out of their
>   teens.

So, Neville's folks also went against Voldemort. That, plus the birth date thing, made Neville eligible for Chosen One Kid.